# How to check if a list of words contains any string

Tags: python-3.x

I want to check if a list of words in a file contains some letters e.g."X and x". 
If a word from list contains this letter, i want to print it.

I tried out something like this:

```
f = open("list.txt", encoding="utf-8")
   text = f.read()
       f.close()

letters = set('x')

for word in text:
    if letters & set(word): 
        print(word)
```

Bu my output contains only "x"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping over **chars**, not **words**. 
If the words in the file are sperated by white-space then here is a quick example:

```
with open("list.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = f.read()
for word in data.lower().split():
    if letters & set(word):
        print(word)
```

Comment: Thanks,

it works. I just added:

letters = set('x')